# Decode base64 string C#

Tags: c#, base64, decode

I tried to decode a following base64 string in C#:

```
PGlmcmFtZSBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9lbWJlZC5yZWR0dWJlLmNvbS8\/aWQ9Mzg1NjAmYmdjb2x
vcj0wMDAwMDAiIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyPSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iNDM0IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjM0NCIgc2Nyb2xsaW5n
PSJubyIgYWxsb3dmdWxsc2NyZWVuPjwvaWZyYW1lPg==
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64  character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Even if i remove last

```
=
```

in the string above but still the same error.

Here is the code i use:

```
    byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(embedCode);
    string decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);
```

Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the correct Base64String is:

```
PGlmcmFtZSBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9lbWJlZC5yZWR0dWJlLmNvbS8/aWQ9Mzg1NjAmYmdjb2x
vcj0wMDAwMDAiIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyPSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iNDM0IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjM0NCIgc2Nyb2xsaW5n
PSJubyIgYWxsb3dmdWxsc2NyZWVuPjwvaWZyYW1lPg==
```

Well this is not a valid Base64String. Base64String can not have `\` character. remove this character and it will work

Comment: @Drew you seem to know what that site is very well :)

Comment: No I am in a mod ish room and we are laughing about it

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani no need to say that warning aloud. you may make him close his account.

Comment: @Sakura my bad, I didn't even look at it. I just paste it as proof that it works. ;)